# Japanese Character Encoding in Base64

Tags: java, encoding, base64, mime

I have been asked to fix a bug in our email processing software.
When a message whose subject is encoded in [RFC 2047](http://tools.ietf.org/pdf/rfc2047.pdf) like this:

```
=?ISO-2022-JP?B?GyRCR1s/LiVGJTklSC1qRnxLXDhsGyhC?=
```

is received, it is incorrectly decoded - one of the Japanese characters is not rendered properly. It is rendered like this: 配信テスト？日本語 when it should be 配信テスト㈱日本語
(I do not understand Japanese) - clearly one of the characters, the one which looks its in brackets, has not been rendered.

The decoding is carried out by `javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility.decodeText()`

If I try it with an on-line decoder (the only one I've found is [here](http://dogmamix.com/MimeHeadersDecoder/)) it seems to work OK, so I was suspecting a bug in `MimeUtility`.

So I tried some experiments, in the form of this little program:

```
public class Encoding {

  private static final Charset CHARSET = Charset.forName("ISO-2022-JP");

  public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        String control = "繋がって";
        String subject= "配信テスト㈱日本語";            

        String controlBase64 = japaneseToBase64(control);
        System.out.println(controlBase64);
        System.out.println(base64ToJapanese(controlBase64));

        String subjectBase64 = japaneseToBase64(subject);
        System.out.println(subjectBase64);
        System.out.println(base64ToJapanese(subjectBase64));

  }

  private static String japaneseToBase64(String in) {
        return Base64.encodeBase64String(in.getBytes(CHARSET));
  }

  private static String base64ToJapanese(String in) {
        return new String(Base64.decodeBase64(in), CHARSET);
  }

}
```

(The `Base64` and `Hex` classes are in `org.apache.commons.codec`)

When I run it, here's the output:

```
GyRCN1IkLCRDJEYbKEI=
繋がって
GyRCR1s/LiVGJTklSCEpRnxLXDhsGyhC
配信テスト？日本語
```

The first, shorter Japanese string is a control, and this returns the same as the input, having been converted into Base64 and back again, using Charset ISO-2022-JP. All OK there.

The second Japanese string is the one with the dodgy character. As you see, it returns with a ? instead of the character. The Base64 encoding output is also different from the original subject encoding.

Sorry if this is long, I wanted to be thorough. What's going on, and how can I decode this character correctly?

Comment: Try using "MS932" in your encoding. Means private static final Charset CHARSET = Charset.forName("MS932");

Comment: Did you try using SHIFT-JIS as charset?

Comment: Well but normally you should convert UTF-8 to Base64 ... this would make it quite easier.

Comment: Using MS932 worked, using SHIFT-JIS produced the same result as before. The Mime encoded string specifies ISO-2022-JP, and I'm not too confortable with ignoring the specified encoding. Still worth a +1 though.

Comment: MS932 is Windows codepage 932, which is effectively JIS X 0208 with Microsoft's extensions. Rather like how you'll also see "latin1" that includes microsoft's smart quotes.

Answer (score 2):

The bug is not in your software, but the subject string itself is incorrectly encoded. Other software may be able to decode the text by making further assumptions about the content, just as it is often assumed that characters in the range 0x80-0x9f are Cp1252-encoded, although ISO-8859-1 or ISO-8859-15 is specified.

ISO-2022-JP is a multi-charset encoding, using escape sequences to switch between the actually used character set. Your encoded string starts with ESC $ B, indicating that the character set JIS X 0208-1983 is used. The offending character is encoded as 0x2d6a. That code point is not defined in the referred character set, but later added to JIS X 0213:2000, a newer version of the JIS X character set specifications.

Answer (score 1):

Try using "MS932" or "Shift-JIS" in your encoding. Means

```
private static final Charset CHARSET = Charset.forName("MS932");
```

There are different scripts in Japanese like kanji, katakana. Some of the encoding like Cp132 will not support some characters of Japanese. The problem you face is because of the encoding "ISO-2022-JP" you have used in your code.

Answer (score 1):

ISO-2022-JP uses pairs of bytes, called ku and ten, that index into a 94×94 table of characters. The pair that fails has ku 12 and ten 73, which is not listed in table of valid characters I have (based on [JIS X 0208](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JIS_X_0208)). All of ku=12 seems to be unused.

Wikipedia doesn't list any updates to JIS X 0208, either. Perhaps the sender is using some sort of vendor-defined extension?

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that `ISO-2022-JP` is a variable width encoding, it seems as though Java doesn't support the section of the character set that it lies in (possibly as a result of the missing escape sequences in `ISO-2022-JP-2` that are present in `ISO-2022-JP-3` and `ISO-2022-JP-2004` which aren't supported). `UTF-8`, `UTF-16` and `UTF-32` do however support all of the characters.

UTF-32:

```
AAB+SwAAMEwAADBjAAAwZg==
繋がって
AACRTQAAT+EAADDGAAAwuQAAMMgAADIxAABl5QAAZywAAIqe
配信テスト㈱日本語
```

As an extra tidbit, regardless of whether `UTF-32` was used, when the strings were printed as-is they retained their natural encoding and appeared normally.